# How do you create multiple self join relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Theres quite a bit of information online on how to do this with the Employee, Manager, Subordinate example but otherwise I couldn't find anything else online.

I'm just trying to create a model schema where the Word object can have many antonyms or many synonyms. These antonyms and synonyms are basically word objects.

I want to be able to run the following:

```
word = Word.create(name:'good')
antonym = Word.create(name:'bad')
word.antonyms << antonym
synonym = Word.create(name:'right')
word.synonyms << synonym

word.antonyms # This gives you a resultset of all of the antonyms related to that word.
```

My models:

```
# The following doesn't work right now
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :antonyms, :foreign_key => 'antonym_id', :class_name => 'Word'
  has_many :synonyms, :foreign_key => 'synonym_id', :class_name => 'Word'   
end

class Antonym < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word, :foreign_key => "word_id", :class_name => "Word"
end

class Synonym < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word, :foreign_key => "word_id", :class_name => "Word"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define `Antonym` and `Synonym` classes.

By specifying the `class_name` option in your `has_many` definitions you are implying that the relations `antonyms` and `synonyms` are of `Word` type.

So remove `Antonym` and `Synonym` classes altogether and keep just the `Word`:

```
# The following doesn't work right now
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :antonyms, :foreign_key => 'antonym_id', :class_name => 'Word'
  has_many :synonyms, :foreign_key => 'synonym_id', :class_name => 'Word'   
end
```

**Update:**

I think the relationship can be `word has_many antonyms` and `word has_many synonyms` instead of `has_many...:through`.

```
class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :antonyms
  has_many :synonyms
end

class Antonym < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word
end

class Synonym < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word
end
```

Then your migration (just to show where the foreign key goes):

```
class CreateWords < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.change
    create_table :words do |t| 
      ...
    end
  end
end

class CreateAntonyms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.change
    create_table :antonyms do |t| 
      t.references :word
      ...
    end
  end
end

class CreateSynonyms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.change
    create_table :synonyms do |t| 
      t.references :word
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

You could imagine a `has_many...:through` relationship on these three models, i.e. `word has_many :synonyms through: :meanings` and similarly `word has_many :antonyms through: :meanings`.  But then the join table `meanings` would need all three `word`, `antonym` and `synonym` for each record which might not be always desirable as adding a word should not require at least one antonym and one synonym.

Comment: I tried removing the other files but its giving me an `unknown attribute: antonym_id` error. Do I need to explicitly add the antonym_id to the model?

Comment: @perseverance, yes you need them(`synonym_id` and `antonym_id`).  They have to be columns in your `words` table.  I was under the impression you already had the columns.

Comment: Currently the Word model has the following columns: word, definition. Now I'm going to add antonym_id, and synonym_id. Do I need to add any other columns?

Comment: @perseverance, for these associations `antonym_id` and `synonym_id` should suffice.

Comment: This only provides an id for one antonym so I can't have many attached to one. What I need is a join table. Do you know how to do this via has_many through?

Comment: @perseverance, please see my update.  I think that will be the most simplest relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply let your `Word` model stay as it is, with the `name` column specifying the type of `Word`. Then when retrieving `antonym` and `synonym`, you can simply scope it

```
scope :antonym, where(name: 'bad')
scope :synonym, where(name: 'right')
```

...

(Of course you can also put it this way `scope :type, ->(type) { where(name: type)} # Word.type('bad') will outputs all the antonyms...)`